# admob for android

Tags: android, web-applications, admob, adwhirl

I followed all the instruction but my ad doesn't appear in my app. My app is already on the market, I configured admob and adwhirl, and it's say it's active, but I can't do it.
Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Your LogCat will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Check, have you added the AdMob activity to you AndroidManifest.xml file? You need something like

`<activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
              />`

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your PublisherID? This was what prevented my ads from appearing.

You could also check your Android logs for any exceptions or problems AdMob might have had.

Answer (score 0):

From the admob pdf documentation:

> When you disable test mode, live ads
>   may not be returned immediately for
>   requests from a new publisher ID or
>   one that has not been used in the past
>   24 hours. You should begin seeing more
>   live ads returned about 15 minutes
>   after your initial live ad requests.
>   Performance generally becomes more
>   consistent once your app is in wider
>   distribution and ad requests are
>   frequently being made from a variety
>   of devices.

I believe you are not seeing ads because of this. It does take a while.